# Toggle same class for the specific item that's being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class, let's call it 'toggle-something' which is defined in CSS, and I would like to apply that class to every item that's being clicked. Question is how could I shorten this code so there's only one click function which would handle all items..?

```
$('.first').on('click', function() {
     $('.item-first').toggleClass('toggle-something');
});

$('.second').on('click', function() {
     $('.item-second').toggleClass('toggle-something');
});

<button class="first">
  <div class="item-first">
    lorem
  </div>
</button>

<button class="second">
  <div class="item-second">
    ipsum
  </div>
</button>

.toggle-something {color: red;}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML markup also.

Comment: Give all clickable elements an additional class `clickable`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('div').toggleClass('toggle-something');
});
```

```css
.toggle-something {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="first">
  <div class="item-first">
    lorem
  </div>
</button>

<button class="second">
  <div class="item-second">
    ipsum
  </div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the * generic selector...

```js
$('*').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
     $(this).toggleClass('toggle-something');
});
```

```css
.toggle-something{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>a</div>
<span>a</span>
<p>a</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the clicked item using `$(this)` which means that you can do something like this:

```
$('.first, .second').on('click', function() {
     $(this).find("div").toggleClass('toggle-something');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this if you want to select which elements that should be able to call the function:

*JS*

```
$('.click').on('click', function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('toggle-something');
});
```

*HTML*

```
<button class="first">
  <div class="item-first click">
    lorem
  </div>
</button>

<button class="second">
  <div class="item-second click">
    ipsum
  </div>
</button>
```

Basically what is done is that you add the class `click` to every element that should be able to start the toggle function.

If you want everything to be able to toggle, then refer to @RenzoCC answer!